# AS2 array gets changed when other array is passed to function?

Tags: arrays, loops, return, actionscript-2, trace

i'm building an Othello AI and ran in to an odd AS2 problem.

When setting a temporary array(arr_temp) equal to the return of a function(timesTen();) by passing the initial array(arr_nums) to it.

Why does it change the initial array as well?

Easiest way i could find to recreate my problem:

```
arr_nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];


timesTen = function(deltaArr){
    for(i = 0; i < deltaArr.length; i ++){
        deltaArr[i] *= 10;
    }
    return(deltaArr);
}


test = function(){
    arr_temp = timesTen(arr_nums);
    trace('temp: ' + arr_temp);
    trace('nums: ' + arr_nums);
}

test();
```

Above code will trace the following:

```
temp: 0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100
nums: 0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100
```

Preferred trace:

```
temp: 0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100
nums: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Even if i don't pass arr_nums and change test as below it will generate the same output:

```
test = function(){
    arr_temp = arr_nums;
    arr_temp = timesTen(arr_temp);
    trace('arr_temp: ' + arr_temp);
    trace('arr_nums: ' + arr_nums);
}
```

Been trying, testing and searching desperately for 2 days now and still got no clue what's wrong and how to fix it?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you declare your variables somewhere? I don't see any "var"

Comment: On line 1 and 13, i used the lazy method "array = [0,1,2...];" instead of "var arr_nums:Array = [0,1,2...];". 
To simplify the code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you actually modify the original array by not using a shallow copy of it.

```
timesTen = function(deltaArr){
    var result = deltaArr.slice();

    for(i = 0; i < result.length; i ++){
        result[i] *= 10;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Just noticed that for a multilevel array you have to slice every sub-array as well in order to deep copy it. Is a for loop the way to go or is there a simple way for this?